# Live USB Stuck at Boot logo on every Distro.

Tags: boot, windows-8, live-usb, macosx

I tried to install a linux OS on a USB. However, after I've tried eOS, Xubuntu and Linux mint, they all failed on the same occation. They all freeze on the logo and never get anywhere. I tried to re-install it all day with different programs (unetbooting, UUI, etc.) but all failed. When I tried opening it on compatibility mode this message shows up.

http://s3.postimg.org/kfj2iuuub/image.jpg

My laptop is MSI GX60 1ac
AMD A10-4600m
AMD Radeon HD 7970M
8GB ram
256GB SSD (win8.1)+750 GB HDD

Installing in 32GB usb, separated in 2 partition. 1 Fat32 1 NTFS (both set primary)

Also, how can I set it to be able to boot on both Windows and Mac?

Please help, first time trying to install linux and failed terribly

Comment: have you resolved the windows hibernation problem? By properly turning them off rather than hibernating?

Comment: Yes. I always turn it off properly before boot it up. Doesn't work anyway

Comment: Can you post a picture where there's no windows hibernation error, as both of these errors seem to be related. Just to be sure.

Comment: you can press f2 usually to see a verbose output. as of right now we really don't have much to go on but if you can post some of the output from when it gets stuck that would really help us figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the USB drive. Some USB sticks don't work as liveUSB sticks. I've had some dodgy sticks in the past (especially Kingston ones). Try another USB stick.

Comment: It seems unrelated, i tried several usb as well but they all got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can instruct Windows what to do when you hit the "Power Button". Your distro is sensing that Windows is hibernating, meaning that your user state is stored on the hard drive and is accessed at boot. To make sure it is not hibernating, go to the control panel, find the power settings, set it to power off, not hibernate, when you hit the off button. By default, it is set to hibernate. Tricky huh? If that doesn't work, it might have to do with "Secure Booting", a BIOS setting. On modern systems, "Secure Booting" interferes w/ what your doing. You can disable it in the BIOS settings, probably the "DEL" key before the OS is loaded. I have to hit F12 (boot menu) for my Live sticks, but I'm already dual booting 8.1 and Ubuntu.
Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

It is likely the usb drive. Alot of usb drives now have "Windows 8 certification" which makes it impossible to boot a live distro. [I would refer here to the faulty ones.](https://tails.boum.org/support/known_issues/#index1h2) You may also need to disable secure boot. Isn't microsoft the worst for messing all this up? Disabling quick boot might also help.

Also, as another user said you may also need to go to the control panel and under change what the power button does in the power settings. Change it to shut down.